# PhpStorm: how to use project root variable or relative path in PhpUnit configuration?

Tags: phpstorm

I would like to setup PhpUnit in PhpStorm. I press  1. Edit Configurations... and would like to enter this parameter in field 2.

[image]

I am using phpunit.xml as configuration file and all want to use a relative path like:

`phpunit.xml`

or use  project root variable like

```
$PROJECT_ROOT/phpunit.xml
```

But both options are not working for me.

Comment: Screenshots of where you are trying to use it, please.

Comment: Thank you for asking, I've just added an screenshot

Comment: I've created a [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-32199) for cross-project Run/Debug configurations.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your screenshot (the place where you want to use it): **use full path** -- in project settings such path is stored relative to the project root anyway (unless you specify some file which is outside of the project, of course) and the full path then reconstructed when needed (e.g. when shown to you or when used as a parameter during tests execution).

Comment: Mine goal is to create a "template" and share it. Because SDK usually is placed in many locations. But it seems like right now I am not able (I don't know how) to use shared template

Comment: @dardarlt You cannot create such "template". All Run/Debug configurations are stored inside `workspace.xml` config file, which is **developer-specific** and not to be shared via VCS. It's better to provide some instructions of how to create it for another user, unless you are happy to edit such config file manually/via some custom script. **In any case (once again):** all paths are stored as relative to the project root unless such path points to outside of the project root.

Comment: I am sorry, I was not very specific. I want to share between my projects. I want save configuration and to use that Share checkmark at the top. But if I open this Sdk project in another location , I am still not able to find how should I apply that saved configuration
I think somehow it's possible.
https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/run-debug-configuration-phpunit.html

Comment: I see information is stored in projects .idea folder, but separate folder - I thought it will be stored in global preferences folder

Comment: Yes -- if you use "Share" option, then such Run/Debug configuration will be saved in `runConfigurations` folder inside `.idea` -- which is still part of this project but now it can be shared via VCS with other team members. It still will not be IDE-wide -- run/debug configurations are very project specific by nature.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll be able to achieve what you want via the project's Run/Debug configurations.  What might help you is the *Default configuration file* setting in your default project settings, which can be used to define the PHPUnit configuration file to use by default, so you don't need to specify it via the *Use alternative configuration file* option in your Run/Debug configuration.

To set this, open your [Default Settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/accessing-default-settings.html) window, then navigate to *Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> PHPUnit*.  In the *Test Runner* section tick the *Default configuration file* checkbox and specify the location where you keep your configuration file.  If this file will always be in the same path relative to your project root, you can use the `$PROJECT_DIR$` variable to define the project root.  So if your PHPUnit configuration file is always in the root of your project, you might set this to something like `$PROJECT_DIR$/phpunit.xml`.  When you create a new project, its *Default configuration file* variable will be set to the file offset from your project root, and you won't need to use the *Use alternative configuration file* option in your Run/Debug configuration.

If you're opening the same project in different locations on the same machine this should work for new projects without any problem, if you want to share this configuration across machines, you might need to try PHPStorm's [Exporting and Importing Settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/exporting-and-importing-settings.html) functionality.

I'm not sure if this directly solves your problem, and it's a few months late anyway, but maybe this will be useful for someone else who stumbles across this question...  The above instructions were correct for my 8.0.3 installation on Linux.